# How to write "group by X where for each row of the grouped result Y in values" in SQL?

Tags: sql

i have the following tuples:

```
A,B
1,1
1,2
2,1
2,4
3,1
3,2
3,4
```

i'm interested in getting all As for which every value of B exists.
basically, i want to group by A and then say "having valueset(B) equals (1,2,4)"

how can i do that?

Comment: Please share with us your database. Do you use Oracle ? SQLServer ?

Comment: Also _specify_ the expected result.

Comment: my expected result is "3" from column A. i was trying to solve this in "standard sql", no fancy functions, so any SQL DB is fine

Answer (score 1):

If this is SQL you can write

```
SELECT A, COUNT(DISTINCT B)
FROM table_name
GROUP BY A
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT B)
= (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT B)
   FROM table_name);
```